# why cant able to save object in jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa-2.0

Actually i am writing a api for only fetching the data from table so i dont need to create table but i need to log each and every call to db .i just commented the spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update in property file to avoiding the table creation on startup. after commenting the jpa auto creation code  i am facing the issue for saving the object (case when id is 0).

> pojos

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "blabla")

public class ABCD{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int xxx;
    private Date yyyy;
   //
   //
}
```

> Saving code

```
model obj = new model(xx, yyy, zzz);
repository.save(obj);
```

Comment: Could you fix the formatting, and be a little more clear on your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably not a good idea to comment that configuration entry, as per [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) in its absence it can be set automatically to `create-drop`, i would suggest you to change it as `none` to avoid any trouble.

> You can set **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto** explicitly and the standard
>   Hibernate property values are *none*, *validate*, *update*, *create*, and
>   *create-drop*. Spring Boot chooses a default value for you based on
>   whether it thinks your database is embedded. It defaults to
>   create-drop if no schema manager has been detected or none in all
>   other cases. An embedded database is detected by looking at the
>   Connection type. hsqldb, h2, and derby are embedded, and others are
>   not. Be careful when switching from in-memory to a ‘real’ database
>   that you do not make assumptions about the existence of the tables and
>   data in the new platform. You either have to set ddl-auto explicitly
>   or use one of the other mechanisms to initialize the database.